# Extract Json field data from array

Tags: json, arraylist, amazon-athena, unnest, json-extract

Trying to query on AWS Athena table which have column containing data as below :

```json
[{'abc': {'field1': 1683215785219, 'field2': None, 'field3': None, 'field4': None, 'field5': 1}, 'emp': '40', 'indicator': False, 'Description': 'AAP: Authorization failure'},{'abc': {'field1': 168321570000, 'field2': None, 'field3': None, 'field4': None, 'field5': 1}, 'emp': '400', 'indicator': False, 'Description': 'AAP: Authorization failure'}]
```

while querying on athena.

Need to get the emp, indicator, Description value but returning empty result.

```sql
select
Description as DESC
from(
select  
   json_extract_scalar(replace(replace(column1, chr(39), chr(34)), ': False', ': false'),'$.id') as id,
   json_format(json_extract(replace(replace(column2 ,chr(39), chr(34)),'None','""'), '$.finance.timing.position'))  as position,column3
from "tablename"  limit 20),
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(column3, '''Description''\s?:\s?\b(\w*)\b', 1)) as t(Description);
```

this query returns empty result.

Also tried using json_parse but that give **INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to json**

Comment: The provided (not)JSON does not contain neither `'$.id'` nor `$.finance.timing.position`.

Comment: Please provide some valid sample data and query which matches it.

Comment: yes , because those are different column.So the table contains column1, column2, column3 and data I am trying to get is from column3